# Displaying SQL SELECT rows in a table display

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

My database structure and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[users] (
    [user_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [user_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [first_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [last_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [id_number] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [user_id] ASC
    )
)

insert into users (user_name, first_name, last_name, id_number)
select 'user1','John','Brown',7707071231
union all
select 'user2','Mary','Jane',7303034432
union all
select 'user3','Peter','Pan',5503024441


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[quiz_results] (
    [result_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [quiz_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [user_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [grade] [bigint] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_quizresults] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [result_id] ASC
    )
)

insert into quiz_results (quiz_id, user_id, grade)
select 1,1,88
union all
select 2,1,84
union all
select 3,1,33
union all
select 1,2,65
```

This query gives me the quiz results for user_id = 1:

```
SELECT
    users.first_name + ' ' + users.last_name + ' (' + users.id_number + ')' AS student_name,
    quiz.quiz_name,
    quiz_results.grade
FROM quiz_results 
INNER JOIN quiz ON quiz_results.quiz_id = quiz.quiz_id
INNER JOIN users ON quiz_results.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE users.user_id = 12345
```

like this:

```
+-------------------------+-----------+-------+
|      student_name       | quiz_name | grade |
+-------------------------+-----------+-------+
| John Brown (7707071231) |  quiz a   |  88   |
| John Brown (7707071231) |  quiz b   |  84   |
| John Brown (7707071231) |  quiz c   |  33   |
+-------------------------+-----------+-------+
```

But I don't want the student_name shown on each row. I want this output:

```
+-------------------------+
| John Brown (7707071231) | 
+-------------------------+
|   quiz a    |     88    |
|   quiz b    |     84    |
|   quiz c    |     33    |
+-------------------------+
```

The student_name is on the first row followed by one row for each quiz result - I specifically want the student_name on the first row.

The query will only ever be for one student_name. Essentially, I want to produce a "certificate" directly in the SQL.

What is the best SQL way to get the data into that format? Will a CTE or the STUFF() command work? Or is there a better way?

Comment: You can't do it in SQL. you can create a stored procedure that will return the student name as an output parameter and the rest of the data as a result set, but you can't have a "column span" in an SQL result set.

Comment: This is definitely something for your presentation layer.

Comment: Pick a presentaiton layer and do it there. SQL only returns tabular data. Take a look at what is in the results window - its 'only ever tabular. The result you want is not tabular. You could probably do it using print statements but _why would you_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply can't be done in SQL.
SQL can only return scalar values or result sets (tabular data), and result sets don't support "column span" - so the only way to do it is in the presentation layer - but you can do some things in SQL Server to make your job in the presentation layer easier.

One option is to create a stored procedure that will return the student name as an output parameter, and the quiz grades as a result set:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetQuizResultByUserId
(
    @UserId int,
    @UserName nvarchar(154) OUTPUT 
)
AS

-- it's 154 because    50     +  1  +     50    +  2   +     50     + 1
SELECT @UserName = first_name + ' ' + last_name + ' (' + id_number + ')'
FROM users
WHERE user_id = @UserId


SELECT
quiz.quiz_name,
quiz_results.grade
FROM quiz_results 
INNER JOIN quiz ON quiz_results.quiz_id = quiz.quiz_id
WHERE quiz_results.user_id = @UserId

GO
```

Another option, since this is 2016 version, is to return the results as Json, using the [`For Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) clause:

```
SELECT first_name + ' ' + last_name + ' (' + id_number + ')' As UserName,
       (
          SELECT quiz.quiz_name,
                 quiz_results.grade
          FROM quiz_results 
          INNER JOIN quiz ON quiz_results.quiz_id = quiz.quiz_id
          WHERE quiz_results.user_id = @UserId
          FOR JSON AUTO
       ) As quizResult
FROM users
WHERE user_id = @UserId
FOR JSON AUTO
```

The result is the following json:

```
[
  {
    "UserName": "John Brown (7707071231)",
    "quizResult": [
      {
        "quiz_name": "quiz a",
        "grade": 88
      },
      {
        "quiz_name": "quiz b",
        "grade": 84
      },
      {
        "quiz_name": "quiz c",
        "grade": 33
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: This didn't solve my problem, but it was the best answer, so accepting it as the answer. Thans for the effort.